# Mock a specific class from a node module in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I would like to mock just the `Socket` class from the `net` node module ([Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)).

I have a class that looks something like this...

```
import { Socket } from 'net';

class Foo {
    protected socket: Socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = new Socket();
    }

    connect() {
        const connPromise = new Promise<undefined>(resolve => {
            this.socket.connect(80, '192.168.1.1', () => {
                // Do some stuff with local state

                resolve();
            });
        });

        return connPromise;
    }
}
```

I am unsure how to mock the Socket class so I can provide the mock implementation for `this.socket.connect`.

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

// Can I just mock the Socket Class somehow?
jest.mock('net')

describe("Foo", () => {
    it('resolves on connect', () => {
        const tester = new Foo();

        expect(tester.connect()).resolves.toBeUndefined();
    })
})
```

How can I control the `this.socket.connect` method implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a [factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) to the mock function:

```
jest.mock('net', () => ({
    Socket: function() {
        return {
            connect() {
                return 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}))
```

(Edited because I forgot you could not reference functions from the outer scope within a jest factory :D)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I needed to mock the class `Resolver` from the `dns` module, but the object was created inside a decorator, this worked for me:

```js
    import {Resolver} from 'dns/promises';
    
    jest.mock('dns/promises');
    
    describe('Some class', () => {
        const resolverMock = jest.mocked(Resolver);
    
        it('should do something', () => {
            resolverMock.prototype
                .resolveCname
                .mockResolvedValue([/* some values here */]);
        });
    });
```