# Jest Typescript Mock specific classes exported by module but not all

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I've been trying to figure out how to best mock specific classes that are exported from a node module. In this case, I have the code that uses the classes `Message` and `TextChannel` and `MessageAttachment` from `discord.js`. I want to mock Message and TextChannel so I can easily set them up for unit testing, but I want the functionality `MessageAttachment` to remain, so I can't just `jest.mock("discord.js")`.

I've tried something similar to:

```
const MockedMessage = jest.Mock<Message>;
const message = new MockedMessage();
message.content = "test"
...
```

That works fine *if the discord.js module is mocked*. However, as stated above, mocking that also mocks the `MessageAttachment` class, whose functionality I want to keep instead of mocking.

I looked at [Mock a specific class from a node module in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772569/mock-a-specific-class-from-a-node-module-in-jest) - but this approach doesn't seem like it would work when using TypeScript unless I am really missing something.

I've also looked in to trying to and then using

```
import * as Discord from 'discord.js'
jest.mock('discord.js')
const {MessageAttachment} = jest.requireActual('discord.js');
Object.defineProperty(Discord, 'MessageAttachment', MessageAttachment);
```

but that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you, that ended up being the answer :) I guess I didn't see that when I looked at initially, but that did the trick.

Comment: @Chris I've read the content linked in the comment provided by @EstusFlask; but, I am missing the answer... you say that it ended up being the answer. Can you please provide exactly what the answer was? I have the same question as you but do not see any answers!!